# Android Update MySQL table through PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am working on an Android App. I need to update a register, I didn't have issues with entries. But when I try to update the table, Doesn't work

this my PHP

```
<?php
require_once 'include/userupdate.php';
$username = "";
$name = "";
$movil="";
$email = "";
$password = "";
$fnac = "";
$calle_numero_piso ="";
$nom_urba = "";
$cod_postal ="";
$localidad="";
$observaciones="";
/////////////////
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
}
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
}
if(isset($_POST['movil'])){
$movil = $_POST['movil'];
}
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
}
if(isset($_POST['password'])){
$password = $_POST['password'];
 } 
if(isset($_POST['fnac'])){
$fnac = $_POST['fnac'];
}
if(isset($_POST['calle_numero_piso'])){
$calle_numero_piso = $_POST['calle_numero_piso'];
}
if(isset($_POST['nom_urba'])){
$nom_urba = $_POST['nom_urba'];
}
if(isset($_POST['cod_postal'])){
$cod_postal = $_POST['cod_postal'];
}
if(isset($_POST['localidad'])){
$localidad = $_POST['localidad'];
}
if(isset($_POST['observaciones'])){
$observaciones = $_POST['observaciones'];
}
// Instance of a User class
$userObject = new User();
// update user
$json_registration = $userObject->updateRegisterUser($username, $name, $movil, $email, $password, $fnac, $calle_numero_piso, $nom_urba, $cod_postal, $localidad, observaciones );
  echo json_encode($json_registration);
 }
 ?>
```

And this my update.php

```
            <?php
        include_once 'db.php';
        class User{
         private $db;
         private $db_table = "users";
         public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new DbConnect();
        }
        mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
        return false;
        }
        public function updateRegisterUser($username, $name, $movil, $email, $password, $fnac, $calle_numero_piso, $nom_urba, $cod_postal, $localidad, $observaciones ){
        $query = "UPDATE users SET name = '$name', movil = '$movil', email = '$email', password = '$password', fnac = '$fnac', calle_numero_piso = '$calle_numero_piso', nom_urba ='$nom_urba', cod_postal = '$cod_postal', localidad = '$localidad', observaciones = '$observaciones' WHERE username = $username;";
        $updated = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);
        if($updated == 1){
        $json['success'] = 1;
        }else{
        $json['success'] = 0;
        }
        mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
        return $json;
        }
        public function loginUsers($username, $password){
        $json = array();
        $canUserLogin = $this->isLoginExist($username, $password);
        if($canUserLogin){
        $json['success'] = 1;
        }else{
        $json['success'] = 0;
        }
        return $json;
        }
        }
        ?>
```

I believe I there is something wrong with both php, but  I am not sure where.

Comment: what error are you getting in your php logs?

Answer (score 1):

try this , as obvious your username is a string so it should be kept inside single quotes

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET name = '$name', movil = '$movil', email = '$email', password = '$password', fnac = '$fnac', calle_numero_piso = '$calle_numero_piso', nom_urba ='$nom_urba', cod_postal = '$cod_postal', localidad = '$localidad', observaciones = '$observaciones' WHERE username = '$username'";
```

One advise for best practice is, always make some primary key recommended as `int autoincrement` which will help to enforce uniqueness because in this case you can have two users with same name which will be a problem when your database grows.